# Win7 Events 6008 and 41

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, event-viewer

I have a Win7 Pro computer that is crashing and turning itself off and on again every couple of days. When i check the event viewer it shows events 6008 and 41 which are system reboot and kernel crash, respectively. The computer doesn't freeze or blue screen beforehand, it just reboots. The computer only runs MS office products, Outlook and virtual PC/XP Mode and it has run these programs for many months if not a year+ without issue.

I have read on a couple of forums that the problems could be caused by overheating, this is untrue for this computer. I also read that it could be caused by faulty drivers, I've checked the device manager and drivers and have found nothing faulty or in-need-of-update.

Most of the advice/solutions that people give on these forums regarding this topic isn't very helpful. Does anyone have a practical "do this" solution rather than general/shotgun approach? Thanks.

[image: Event Viewer]

Comment: Computer is arbitrarily hard-power-off, but not cooling or driver related. Check for and remove recently-installed software. Make sure you're patched and check for an install any updated drivers and BIOS or other hardware firmware (just checking for errors in Device Manager is not enough).

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504